# How to force Kured in AKS to trigger reboot e.g. when testing notifications?

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I'm trying to trigger Kured reboot in order to test it's notification. However, for some reason manually creating sentinel file doesn't trigger reboot.

```
time="2021-11-19T06:32:53Z" level=info msg="Reboot schedule: SunMonTueWedThuFriSat between 00:00 and 23:59 UTC"
time="2021-11-19T06:32:53Z" level=info msg="Reboot check command: [test -f /var/run/reboot-required] every 15m0s"
time="2021-11-19T06:32:53Z" level=info msg="Reboot command: [/bin/systemctl reboot]"
time="2021-11-19T06:52:52Z" level=info msg="Reboot not required"
time="2021-11-19T07:07:52Z" level=info msg="Reboot not required"
```

**Preconditions**

- Kured is installed with such a configuration that will trigger notification during verification (e.g. period, start-time, end-time and notify-url)
- Use following commands to list the kured pods and check logs in the specific one:

```
kubectl get pods -n kured -o wide | grep kured
kubectl logs -n kured <kured pod name> -f
```

**Info and steps**

- Kured checks whether sentinel file /var/run/reboot-required exists
- Kured has an option to specify notification url (--notify-url) for e.g. slack or teams channel
- Instructions to SSH into AKS Linux node https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ssh

**Manually create sentinel file**

- SSH into a node in which Kured is installed
- Create sentinel file according to instructions in https://github.com/weaveworks/kured

```
touch /var/run/reboot-required
```